# Antd Custom button not triggering dropdown

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, antd

Can someone explain to me why the dropdown trigger is not being executed when I use my custom button? Where do I declare OnClick as I use CustomButton in other areas

[image: Edit empty-microservice-4xhjr]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dropdown` of Antd passes a prop called `onClick` to its children `CustomButton`, and you need to pass it to the button inside `CustomButton`:

```
const CustomButton = props => {
  return <Button type={props.type} onClick={props.onClick}>{props.text}</Button>;
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-architecture-8x1fx)

Answer (score 0):

For guys who is using antd pro-component: 
If you find you are using a custom suffix icon, but click it cannot trigger dropdown action. Based on the official documentation, please add `pointer-events: none` to the icon style:
[official documentation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm1VD.png)

```
<ProFormSelect
    fieldProps={{
        suffixIcon: (
            <CustomIcon
                type='ChevronDown'
                style={{ color: 'var(--word-disable-color)', fontSize: 14, pointerEvents: 'none' }}
            />
        ),
        ...fieldProps,
    }}
    {...rest}
/>
```